# Test Mobx inject component

Tags: reactjs, mobx

i'm having trouble testing a component with Mobx inject and jest.
this is the component:

```js
@inject("mainStore") @observer
export default class TestContainer extends React.Component {
    sum(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }
    render() {
        return <div className="TestContainer">phhhaz</div>
    }
}
```

this is a the test:

```js
describe('TestContainer', () => {
it('knows that 2 and 2 make 4', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TestContainer mainStore={{}} />);
    expect(wrapper.instance().sum(2,2)).toBe(4);
});
});
```

i'm getting this error:

```js
TypeError: wrapper.instance(...).sum is not a function
```

i know why it's happening but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried with `mount` instead of `shallow`?

Comment: yes i did...
Error: It looks like you called `mount()` without a global document being loaded.

Comment: You can use a headless browser like [**jsdom**](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/jsdom.md).

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that you are shallow rendering the inject component. And since it is a wrapping component (Hoc) you are not testing your own component at all. Instead of rendering and testing `TestContainer` you should be rendering and testing `TestContainer.wrappedComponent`. For more details see: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#testing-store-injection